# How to update an s3 bucket created with cloud formation via cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

We have a production s3 bucket created a few years ago with maybe a dozen files in it that was created via cloud formation. Im looking to update the template by adding a Notification Configuration to our bucket. Im getting the 'bucket already exists' error in cloud formation though when trying to run the update. From what I understand from the s3 notification though I should be able to update this property without deleting the resource.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html

> NotificationConfiguration
> Configuration that defines how Amazon S3 handles bucket notifications.

> Required: No

> Type: NotificationConfiguration

> Update requires: No interruption

Further, in our development account where i am able to access the AWS console I can attach an s3 event to our lambda and the development version of this bucket. This leads me to believe there must be a way to update the production bucket via cloud formation without taking everything out, deleting it, and recreating it with the Notification Configuration on it.

Does anyone know how I would do this via cloud formation?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: AWS CloudFormation template for Kafka Resource Selector Upload Bucket
Parameters:
  BucketName:
    Description: Bucket's name
    Type: String
  S3KmsKeyID:
    Description: KMS Key ID used for encryption
    Type: String
  lambdaFunctionArn:
    Description: arn for the target lambda function
    Type: String
Resources:
  S3ENILambdaUploadBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      BucketName: 
        !Ref BucketName
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              KMSMasterKeyID: !Ref S3KmsKeyID
              SSEAlgorithm: aws:kms
      NotificationConfiguration:
        LambdaConfigurations:
        - Event: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'
          Function: !Ref lambdaFunctionArn
      Tags:
        -
         Key: "Purpose"
         Value: "ENI Resource Selector Lambda Upload Bucket"
Outputs:
  S3BucketName:
    Value:
      Ref: S3ENILambdaUploadBucket
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-lambda-upload-bucket"
```

Events

2021-09-03 16:04:55 UTC-0400    my-prod-s3bucket    UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE    -
2021-09-03 16:04:54 UTC-0400    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket DELETE_COMPLETE -
2021-09-03 16:04:53 UTC-0400    my-prod-s3bucket    UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS    -
2021-09-03 16:04:52 UTC-0400    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket UPDATE_COMPLETE -
2021-09-03 16:04:24 UTC-0400    my-prod-s3bucket    UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS The following resource(s) failed to update: [S3ENILambdaUploadBucket].
2021-09-03 16:04:23 UTC-0400    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket UPDATE_FAILED   ap128110-uat-s3bucket already exists
2021-09-03 16:04:23 UTC-0400    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS  Requested update requires the creation of a new physical resource; hence creating one.
2021-09-03 16:04:16 UTC-0400    my-prod-s3bucket    UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS  User Initiated

2019-11-05 21:25:31 UTC-0500    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket CREATE_COMPLETE -
2019-11-05 21:25:10 UTC-0500    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  Resource creation Initiated
2019-11-05 21:25:09 UTC-0500    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2019-11-05 21:25:05 UTC-0500    my-prod-s3bucket    CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  User Initiated

I turned on physical id in the cloud formation events page and it seems someone hijacked this stack to create a second bucket at some point. In august of this year it looks like it created my-prod-yamlbucket Im wondering if this disassociated this stack with the original my-prod-s3bucket and now theres no way to update my-prod-s3bucket.

```
2021-09-03 16:04:55 UTC-0400    my-prod-s3bucket    UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE    -   AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:MYACCOUNTNUMBER:stack/my-prod-s3bucket/a5249fa0-003c-11ea-b932-0aad1b9980b2    -
2021-09-03 16:04:54 UTC-0400    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket DELETE_COMPLETE -   AWS::S3::Bucket -   -
2021-09-03 16:04:53 UTC-0400    my-prod-s3bucket    UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS    -   AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:MYACCOUNTNUMBER:stack/my-prod-s3bucket/a5249fa0-003c-11ea-b932-0aad1b9980b2    -
2021-09-03 16:04:52 UTC-0400    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket UPDATE_COMPLETE -   AWS::S3::Bucket my-prod-yamlbucket  -
2021-09-03 16:04:24 UTC-0400    my-prod-s3bucket    UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS The following resource(s) failed to update: [S3ENILambdaUploadBucket].  AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:MYACCOUNTNUMBER:stack/my-prod-s3bucket/a5249fa0-003c-11ea-b932-0aad1b9980b2    -
2021-09-03 16:04:23 UTC-0400    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket UPDATE_FAILED   my-prod-s3bucket already exists AWS::S3::Bucket my-prod-yamlbucket  -
2021-09-03 16:04:23 UTC-0400    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS  Requested update requires the creation of a new physical resource; hence creating one.  AWS::S3::Bucket my-prod-yamlbucket  -
2021-09-03 16:04:16 UTC-0400    my-prod-s3bucket    UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS  User Initiated  AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:MYACCOUNTNUMBER:stack/my-prod-s3bucket/a5249fa0-003c-11ea-b932-0aad1b9980b2    
2021-08-17 16:21:30 UTC-0400    my-prod-s3bucket    UPDATE_COMPLETE Update successful. One or more resources could not be deleted.  AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:MYACCOUNTNUMBER:stack/my-prod-s3bucket/a5249fa0-003c-11ea-b932-0aad1b9980b2    -
2021-08-17 16:21:29 UTC-0400    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket DELETE_FAILED   The bucket you tried to delete is not empty (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 409; Error Code: BucketNotEmpty; Request ID: V1ACVVRYDMBT1XHF; S3 Extended Request ID: b5PP8cGSD/kN3qHUkVeDPWYLob9GvBt1v36/8ZTk44on5iu9iTv7ndVqBgukm+g3qhq1PXcBWic=; Proxy: null) AWS::S3::Bucket my-prod-s3bucket    -
2021-08-17 16:21:29 UTC-0400    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket DELETE_IN_PROGRESS  -   AWS::S3::Bucket my-prod-s3bucket    -
2021-08-17 16:18:27 UTC-0400    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket DELETE_FAILED   The bucket you tried to delete is not empty (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 409; Error Code: BucketNotEmpty; Request ID: HXHBCT90T3NK06DA; S3 Extended Request ID: 1+THuwBkVxwWrc1F1GxAujP6/sNGnanRno9wdit1dpVuRuFYRs9Yi4KR8KNkR9te06pVjMQyRMo=; Proxy: null) AWS::S3::Bucket my-prod-s3bucket    -
2021-08-17 16:18:27 UTC-0400    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket DELETE_IN_PROGRESS  -   AWS::S3::Bucket my-prod-s3bucket    -
2021-08-17 16:15:25 UTC-0400    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket DELETE_FAILED   The bucket you tried to delete is not empty (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 409; Error Code: BucketNotEmpty; Request ID: X8PX7T254K0EFNC8; S3 Extended Request ID: V5TiUbB+iltwr5tLrmJqw5wnQ7nDwXgLZGKVDyy917ro6x1dlNcbY2s+ZrKnEMwKnQh7cjXz8rk=; Proxy: null) AWS::S3::Bucket my-prod-s3bucket    -
2021-08-17 16:15:24 UTC-0400    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket DELETE_IN_PROGRESS  -   AWS::S3::Bucket my-prod-s3bucket    -
2021-08-17 16:15:23 UTC-0400    my-prod-s3bucket    UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS -   AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:MYACCOUNTNUMBER:stack/my-prod-s3bucket/a5249fa0-003c-11ea-b932-0aad1b9980b2    -
2021-08-17 16:15:21 UTC-0400    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket UPDATE_COMPLETE -   AWS::S3::Bucket my-prod-yamlbucket  -
2021-08-17 16:14:59 UTC-0400    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS  Resource creation Initiated AWS::S3::Bucket my-prod-yamlbucket  -
2021-08-17 16:14:59 UTC-0400    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS  Requested update requires the creation of a new physical resource; hence creating one.  AWS::S3::Bucket my-prod-s3bucket    -
2021-08-17 16:14:51 UTC-0400    my-prod-s3bucket    UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS  User Initiated  AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:MYACCOUNTNUMBER:stack/my-prod-s3bucket/a5249fa0-003c-11ea-b932-0aad1b9980b2    -
2021-07-01 00:14:52 UTC-0400    my-prod-s3bucket    UPDATE_COMPLETE -   AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:MYACCOUNTNUMBER:stack/my-prod-s3bucket/a5249fa0-003c-11ea-b932-0aad1b9980b2    -
2021-07-01 00:14:52 UTC-0400    my-prod-s3bucket    UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS -   AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:MYACCOUNTNUMBER:stack/my-prod-s3bucket/a5249fa0-003c-11ea-b932-0aad1b9980b2    -
2021-07-01 00:14:49 UTC-0400    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket UPDATE_COMPLETE -   AWS::S3::Bucket my-prod-s3bucket    -
2021-07-01 00:14:29 UTC-0400    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS  -   AWS::S3::Bucket my-prod-s3bucket    -
2021-07-01 00:14:23 UTC-0400    my-prod-s3bucket    UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS  User Initiated  AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:MYACCOUNTNUMBER:stack/my-prod-s3bucket/a5249fa0-003c-11ea-b932-0aad1b9980b2    -
2021-07-01 00:08:49 UTC-0400    my-prod-s3bucket    UPDATE_COMPLETE -   AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:MYACCOUNTNUMBER:stack/my-prod-s3bucket/a5249fa0-003c-11ea-b932-0aad1b9980b2    -
2021-07-01 00:08:48 UTC-0400    my-prod-s3bucket    UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS -   AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:MYACCOUNTNUMBER:stack/my-prod-s3bucket/a5249fa0-003c-11ea-b932-0aad1b9980b2    -
2021-07-01 00:08:46 UTC-0400    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket UPDATE_COMPLETE -   AWS::S3::Bucket my-prod-s3bucket    -
2021-07-01 00:08:26 UTC-0400    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS  -   AWS::S3::Bucket my-prod-s3bucket    -
2021-07-01 00:08:21 UTC-0400    my-prod-s3bucket    UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS  User Initiated  AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:MYACCOUNTNUMBER:stack/my-prod-s3bucket/a5249fa0-003c-11ea-b932-0aad1b9980b2    -
2019-11-05 21:25:34 UTC-0500    my-prod-s3bucket    CREATE_COMPLETE -   AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:MYACCOUNTNUMBER:stack/my-prod-s3bucket/a5249fa0-003c-11ea-b932-0aad1b9980b2    -
2019-11-05 21:25:31 UTC-0500    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket CREATE_COMPLETE -   AWS::S3::Bucket my-prod-s3bucket    -
2019-11-05 21:25:10 UTC-0500    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  Resource creation Initiated AWS::S3::Bucket my-prod-s3bucket    -
2019-11-05 21:25:09 UTC-0500    S3ENILambdaUploadBucket CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  -   AWS::S3::Bucket -   -
2019-11-05 21:25:05 UTC-0500    my-prod-s3bucket    CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  User Initiated  AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:MYACCOUNTNUMBER:stack/my-prod-s3bucket/a5249fa0-003c-11ea-b932-0aad1b9980b2
```

Comment: This should be possible in cloudformation without needing to replace. Are there any other errors showing up in the console?

Comment: Can you also show the change set of the cloudformation when updating ?

Comment: Are you sure you are updating the correct cloudformation template used for creating the bucket? Is the bucket in production created manually or in cloudformation?

Comment: I put the cloudformation output. its just the one error. I am updating the original stack that created the bucket

Comment: What command are you using to deploy this template? Also what's the event before the oldest event you shared?

Comment: Im using a concourse job to deploy it. That is the oldest event in the cloud formation stack